Series and convergence of the step series
Consider a converging series $S$ such that $$S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_{n}.$$
Is there some result about the convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\cdot(x_{n}-x_{n+1})\;?$$

What about the case $x_n=\frac \sin(n) \sqrt{n}$.

Are you familiar with Summation by Parts, which is a discrete analog of Integration by Parts? Mess around with this formula applied to your partial sums $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k$ and see what additional hypotheses you need in order to establish convergence.

Suppose $b_n=n(x_n-x_{n+1})$ and $S_n = x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n$. Then, it is given that
$$S=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} S_n.$$
Suppose, we denote
$$P_n = b_1+b_2+\dots b_n.$$
Then, it is an easy calculation that
$$P_n = x_1+x_2+\dots +x_{n-1}-nx_{n+1} = S_n-nx_{n+1}.$$
Clearly, $P_n$ converges if and only if the sequence $\{nx_{n+1}\}$ converges.
Now the task is: can you think of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $\sum x_n$ converges, but $nx_{n+1}$ does not converge? (There is such a sequence).

Very good point, thanks for the explanation.
And some kind of alternate serie term like (-1)^n/n would converge in the serie but not along the criteria.

Exactly. Right.

If you found it useful, you can accept the answer, if you feel like this was what you were looking for.
